# InteropServices not found - unable to resolve

Tags: c#

I'm a little lost. I've been working on this project for 2 years now and I decided to reinstall my OS to have a smoother working experience again.

The Setup I use is Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. The Project itself was written with `.net 4.6.1`

Since reinstalling the OS my C# project crashes upon start.

```
Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : The service terminated abnormally, 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly 
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=(token)" oder eine Abhängigkeit wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I reinstalled & updated all NuGet Packages and I am lost on how to fix the System.Runtime.InteropServices Error.

According to other Resources `InteropService` requires `.net 4.7.1` but this didn't solve my issue.

When I try to add `System.Runtime.InteropServices` manually it does not get listed (I guess because it keeps looking for .NET Framework 4.6.1:

[image]

Comment: did you tick the correct dotnet framework version while installing vs?

Comment: I installed with .net 6.x and installed 4.6.1 and 4.7.1 afterwards

Comment: Check also the assembly bindings in the `App.config`: there might be a version redirection for the `System.Runtime.InteropServices`

Comment: Why are you targeting .NET 4.6.1? I don't believe there is any good reason to continue using that old, old release. Why can't you target .NET Framework 4.8 instead?

Comment: @kyrylomyr ```<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>```

is in my `app.config`

Comment: we are currently rewriting for the current version and this is just to maintain the older program

Comment: @HadiBazmi I checked within the Visual Studio Installer again and made sure to install .Net Framework 4.6.1 and 4.7.1 but the error still occurs.

Comment: you may also check <targetframwork> in app/webconfig, to fix this '(I guess because it keeps looking for .NET Framework 4.6.1)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't quite understand why, but there is a difference between updating NuGet Packages from the Console vs. the Interface. The Interface didn't work for me.

Under `Extra > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console` you can run the `Update-Package`. This did the trick for me.